# Should MSO profile page include links to your questions and answers on the other sites too?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trilogy Portal: Community Colloboration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6033/trilogy-portal-community-colloboration)

Since the launch of SO one of my morning rituals became logging into my profile to see what's happened with the questions and answers I'd left the previous night. It's often at the end of a hard day with unresolved problems do I resort to the community for help.

These days I basically do the same, but it takes several more clicks and browser tabs for SO/SF/SU/MSO. And I'm sure as time goes on there will be even more.

Since MSO is supposed to be abstractly related to ALL these sites, would it be a good idea for it to include links to ALL the Questions and Answers from ALL your linked profiles in a single page?

Comment: So, it's like you want everything to be accessible from one place. A portal if you will?

Comment: Possible dupage: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6033/trilogy-portal-community-colloboration

Comment: dup http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=portal

Answer (score 1):

I think it's time we start making a distinction between the sites. It's a FAMILY, and all members are distinct for a reason. It think a lot more emphasis needs to be made around this point.

When you're on Youtube do you expect to get GMail notifications? Yes, it would be a nice feature for some, but the sites really need to be handled separately.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to say this is not a great idea. Every site has its purpose and the questions should stay with them.  MSO has its own set of questions and I do not think it should all be mixed on your MSO profile.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way in which that would work... but with the little yellow envelope (and a few browser bookmarks), I find it pretty easy to check for answers/comments/etc over the sites, and if you are interested in votes then [Jon's tracker](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx) might help.